# An error occurred while displaying the result of the request in a text component. using the fetch () method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It is not an error in fact, but it is not showing the result of the request in the component.

First I made the request, and I want to show the response of my request in a Text component, but the empty component appears when rendering

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

    url = 'https://b7web.com.br/todo/25088';

this.state = {
  lista:''
}

carregaDados = () => {
  fetch(this.url)
    .then(
      (res)=> res.json()
    )
    .then(
      (res)=>this.setState({lista:res.todo})
    );
}
  }


  render(){
     return(
  <View>
    <Text>{this.state.lista}</Text>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show how res is structured?

Comment: {
      todo: [
{
id: "7317",
item: "Item 1",
done: "0"
},
{
id: "7318",
item: "Item 2",
done: "0"
},
{
id: "7319",
item: "Item 3",
done: "0"
},
{
id: "7323",
item: "Comprar pizza",
done: "0"
},
{
id: "7324",
item: "Fazer trabalho",
done: "0"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to render an array of objects inside a  component and also you haven't gived the `View` a style, making render every children inside a single line.

If you want to render an element you have to cycle trough the array trough a `.map()` or use a `Flatlist`.

An example would be:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   {this.state.lista!==''&&this.state.lista.map((item, index) => 
      <Text key={index}>{item.item}</Text>
   }
    </View>
```